# Cannot paste folder to system files - error read only

Tags: files, filesystem

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate - i  tried searching for answers to this problem but the solutions seems to only governs flash drives or virtual machines.

I am trying to paste a folder from my home directory into some system files. This is what i tried:

```
sudo cp -r /home/renec/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas /snap/blender/30/2.80/python/lib/python3.7/
```

What I get is:

```
cp: cannot create directory '/snap/blender/30/2.80/python/lib/python3.7/pandas': Read-only file system
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that the clue lays in the last part of the error message; `Read-only file system` ... The snap is mounted read-only as part of the sandboxing to prevent you from messing with the content. Install a normal .deb package instead.

Comment: Can't I update the system instead?